# Visible website, but apache gets a 404

Tags: apache, virtualhost

My website is visible (http://www.nowis-informatique.fr) but when I try a :

```
curl -I http://www.nowis-informatique.fr/assets/front/img/slider/2/-tincelles-de-couleurs_480x480.png
```

My header is :

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 16 Jan 2015 13:14:41 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

But when i try with arg -4 on curl, it's work.

---

Reallity problem :

When sharing a facebook page (if I copy the URL in a new Facebook status, for example), the image and description generated by Facebook is not at all that of my site, but homepage of my server.

example: www.nowis-informatique.fr

Accessible without worries from my browser. When I put the URL into a facebook status he me out of my server page "87.106.242.7" ...

On this server I have several field and it does the same for them. I want to say that everything worked on 09.22.2014, the date of my last Facebook publication.

I looked on the developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ software The return code is 206, and the information is that of my "87.106.242.7" obviously ...

I do not know how strictly fix the problem ...

Thank you all

Apache v2.2

Comment: same command gave me `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` ...`Content-Type: image/png`.

Comment: can you check your server's access_log, it will tell you where the requests are going from your end.

Comment: this could be because of ipv6. try with command `curl -4 -I http://www.nowis-informatique.fr/assets/front/img/slider/2/-tincelles-de-couleurs_480x480.png`